# Low quality picture and what's the usage of overriding surfaceChanged when using Android Camera API

Tags: android, image, android-camera

I have a problem for my application, specifically, when I want to take a picture (from android Camera API) and send it to my server, I got some strange pictures like following example:

[image]

[image]

which contain many noise points and actually the size/resolution are very small (176*144 pixels). And this is my original code for surfaceChanged:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

And I tried to ask some classmates for this issue, they don't know but one of them give the following code:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    try {
        // camera.stopPreview();
        // Camera.Parameters mParameters = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size optiSize = getBestPreviewSize(720, 720);
        if (optiSize != null) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(optiSize.width, optiSize.height);
            parameters.setPictureSize(optiSize.width, optiSize.height);
        }
        parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();

        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        }
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        // mParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        // camera.setParameters(mParameters); // apply the changes
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // older phone - doesn't support these calls
    }
    mCamera.startPreview();
}


private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height) {
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = mCamera.getParameters()
            .getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    if (sizes == null)
        return null;
    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    int tmpSize;

    int minWidthDiff = 1000;
    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        if (size.width > size.height)
            tmpSize = size.height;
        else
            tmpSize = size.width;
        if (Math.abs(tmpSize - width) < minWidthDiff) {
            minWidthDiff = Math.abs(tmpSize - width);
            optimalSize = size;
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

And this one works pretty well, it can store the original picture with the full resolution. Although I modify a little bit of my other codes to make the new codes compatible with my system, (add AutoFocus, for example). But I think the problem occurs because the method surfaceChanged because if I take image only with Autofocus, it still not work.

Therefore my question is: why this method will influence the quality of my image. I thought this method is only called when we "change" the surface, something like rotate the screen. But apparently it do something more than that?

Can anybody give me some help? Or some posts to explain this fact? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is called when the surface is changed, e.g. it is resized. It is common to adjust some of the camera's parameters to better fit the new configurations (such as setting an appropriate preview size).

What you are doing in the first code is you're getting the camera's `Camera.Parameters`, set a key-value pair (by the way, [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) does not mention any parameter with the key `"orientation"` - it probably has no meaning). What you forgot to do is to apply the new parameters to the camera using `Camera.setParameters()`. Then again, without actually setting any valid parameters, this would have no effect.

This leads to the low-quality picture issue. You should use the `Camera.Parameters` object to set a desired preview and picture size. In the second block of code, this is done inside `getBestPreviewSize()`. A list of available preview sizes is got and the most fitting one is chosen based on the preview's size. It might be helpful to set a satisfactory picture size, too.

The thing is, different devices have different set of supported values for the parameters. If you want to provide a consistent functionality, you should check the supported values using `Camera.Parameters.getSupported*` methods and set them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helps me.